# Duplicating declarations in a swift playgground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

is there a way to introduce the concept of 'scope' while trying things out in playground?

Say you want to test a couple of implementations of a class **MyClass** so you declare it, write some code to test things. You then decide you want to compare that with another version of class MyClass implementation.

Redeclaring MyClass will give a redeclaration error.

So can I have playground treat the first declaration of MyClass and associated code separately from the second without changing the class name or creating multiple playgrounds?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can use [nested types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH23-ID242) for this – declare a `struct` the only purpose of which is to have this kind of scoping:

```
struct Scope1 {
    class MyClass { }
}

struct Scope2 {
    class MyClass { }
}

let x = Scope1.MyClass()
let y = Scope2.MyClass()

// if you want to quickly switch between using 
// one vs the other
typealias MyClass = Scope1.MyClass
let z = MyClass()
```

Comment: Hey Airspeed, that is the best solution (hack)  but was hoping for something better :) thank you for the suggestion and also thanks to @Dreaming In Binary.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Playground files are order-dependent and run in top-down lexical order.